# How do I write in the RTL Text Input field on TextMeshProUGUI from a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to write in the RTL Text Input field, but I don't know how to access it from a script.

TextMeshPro.(?)

[image: I want to write int the RTL Text Input field from script]

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the script (or GameObject), and then call it like:

```
public class YourTextHandlerComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI textRef;

    private void Awake()
    {
        textRef.text = "your new text";
    }
}
```

so the answer is `".text"`, remember that RTL editor will only reverse the order of characters contained in "text", won't make character substitution.

*Keep in mind that there are 2 similar TextMesh components, `TextMeshPro` and `TextMeshProUGUI`, one is for 3D space and the other for UI space, just to keep in mind when you type your reference type on your script.*

Comment: Anyway, thanks for expanding upon your code sample and fixing the compilation issue.  That was the main thing.  Yours is a fine answer. +1